# Keyboard input Delay In Python file

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, delay

Hey I'm trying to solve a problem where whenever i turnoff this code through exe file. My keybord gets deplayed to fix that i have to either turn off the program window or turn it back on.

Can anyone fix this code remove this keybord delay cause im still new to coding.
what to do can anyone explain plz

```py
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import time
import ctypes
import PIL.ImageGrab
import PIL.Image
import winsound 
import os
import mss
from colorama import Fore, Style, init
S_HEIGHT, S_WIDTH = (PIL.ImageGrab.grab().size)
PURPLE_R, PURPLE_G, PURPLE_B = (250, 100, 250)
TOLERANCE = 31
GRABZONE = 10
TRIGGER_KEY = "ctrl + alt"
SWITCH_KEY = "ctrl + tab"
GRABZONE_KEY_UP = "ctrl + up"
BUNNY_KEY = "ctrl + space"
GRABZONE_KEY_DOWN = "ctrl + down"
mods = ["OPERATOR/MARSHAL", "GUARDIAN", "VANDAL/PHANTOM/SHOTGUNS"]
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
 
class FoundEnemy(Exception):
    pass
 
class triggerBot():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.toggled = False
        self._bunny = False
        self.mode = 1
        self.last_reac = 0
 
    def toggle(self) -> None: self.toggled = not self.toggled
    def bunnyy(self) -> None: self._bunny = not self._bunny
 
    def switch(self):
        if self.mode != 2: self.mode += 1
        else: self.mode = 0
        if self.mode == 0: winsound.Beep(200, 200)
        if self.mode == 1: winsound.Beep(200, 200), winsound.Beep(200, 200)
        if self.mode == 2: winsound.Beep(200, 200), winsound.Beep(200, 200), winsound.Beep(200, 200)
 
    def click(self) -> None:
        ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0,0) # sol bas
        ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0,0) # sol bırak
 
    def approx(self, r, g ,b) -> bool: return PURPLE_R - TOLERANCE < r < PURPLE_R + TOLERANCE and PURPLE_G - TOLERANCE < g < PURPLE_G + TOLERANCE and PURPLE_B - TOLERANCE < b < PURPLE_B + TOLERANCE
 
    def grab(self) -> None:
        with mss.mss() as sct:
            bbox=(int(S_HEIGHT/2-GRABZONE), int(S_WIDTH/2-GRABZONE), int(S_HEIGHT/2+GRABZONE), int(S_WIDTH/2+GRABZONE))
            sct_img = sct.grab(bbox)
            return PIL.Image.frombytes('RGB', sct_img.size, sct_img.bgra, 'raw', 'BGRX')
 
    def scan(self) -> None:
        start_time = time.time()
        pmap = self.grab()
 
        try:
            for x in range(0, GRABZONE*2):
                for y in range(0, GRABZONE*2):
                    r, g, b = pmap.getpixel((x,y))
                    if self.approx(r, g, b): raise FoundEnemy
        except FoundEnemy:
            self.last_reac = int((time.time() - start_time)*1000)
            self.click()
            if self.mode == 0: time.sleep(0.5)
            if self.mode == 1: time.sleep(0.25)
            if self.mode == 2: time.sleep(0.1)
            print_banner(self)
 
    def bunny(self) -> None:
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("space"): pyautogui.press("space")
            else: break
def print_banner(bot: triggerBot) -> None:
    os.system("cls")
    print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.CYAN + "                      ​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​ - ​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​                  " + Style.RESET_ALL)
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
    print("===== Controls =====")
    print("Activate   :", Fore.YELLOW + TRIGGER_KEY + Style.RESET_ALL)
    print("Change Gun  :", Fore.YELLOW + SWITCH_KEY + Style.RESET_ALL)
    print("FOV Circle Size(I Think)  :", Fore.YELLOW + GRABZONE_KEY_UP + "/" + GRABZONE_KEY_DOWN + Style.RESET_ALL)
    print("Bunny Hop  :", Fore.YELLOW + BUNNY_KEY + Style.RESET_ALL)
    print("==== Settings ===")
    print("Gun                  :", Fore.CYAN + mods[bot.mode] + Style.RESET_ALL)
    print("FOV Circle       :", Fore.CYAN + str(GRABZONE) + "x" + str(GRABZONE) + Style.RESET_ALL)
    print("Trigger Bot       :", (Fore.GREEN if bot.toggled else Fore.RED) + ("Enabled" if bot.toggled else "Disabled") + Style.RESET_ALL)
    print("Bunny-Hop         :", (Fore.GREEN if bot._bunny else Fore.RED) + ("Enabled" if bot._bunny else "Disabled") + Style.RESET_ALL)
    print("T-Bot Reactime Time :", Fore.CYAN + str(bot.last_reac) + Style.RESET_ALL + " ms ("+str((bot.last_reac)/(GRABZONE*GRABZONE))+"ms/pix)")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = triggerBot()
    print_banner(bot)
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(SWITCH_KEY):
            bot.switch()
            print_banner(bot)
            while keyboard.is_pressed(SWITCH_KEY): pass
        if keyboard.is_pressed(GRABZONE_KEY_UP):
            GRABZONE += 5
            print_banner(bot)
            winsound.Beep(400, 200)
            while keyboard.is_pressed(GRABZONE_KEY_UP): pass
        if keyboard.is_pressed(GRABZONE_KEY_DOWN):
            GRABZONE -= 5
            print_banner(bot)
            winsound.Beep(300, 200)
            while keyboard.is_pressed(GRABZONE_KEY_DOWN): pass
        if keyboard.is_pressed(TRIGGER_KEY):
            bot.toggle()
            print_banner(bot)
            if bot.toggled: winsound.Beep(440, 75), winsound.Beep(700, 100)
            else: winsound.Beep(440, 75), winsound.Beep(200, 100)
            while keyboard.is_pressed(TRIGGER_KEY): pass
        if keyboard.is_pressed(BUNNY_KEY): 
            bot.bunny()
            print_banner(bot)
            if bot._bunny: winsound.Beep(440, 75), winsound.Beep(700, 100)
            else: winsound.Beep(440, 75), winsound.Beep(200, 100)
            while keyboard.is_pressed(BUNNY_KEY): pass
 
        if bot.toggled: bot.scan()
        if bot._bunny:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("space"): bot.bunny()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might implement a break condition in the main loop to allow for interruption or termination of the script.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = triggerBot()
    print_banner(bot)

    running = True  # Flag to control the main loop

    while running:  # Main loop controlled by the 'running' flag
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # Press 'q' to exit the loop and terminate the script
            running = False
            break
    # Rest of your code 
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: driver.quit() not working its not opening

Comment: pls make sure driver instance is alive before quit .

Comment: Broooooo couldn't found where to add  this code its just isn't working T_T nvm then ig